# Starting Learning node.js - Their Simple Server Sample Gives Syntax Errors

Tags: node.js, syntax-error, sample

Using the code sample found [here](https://nodejs.org/en/learn/getting-started/introduction-to-nodejs), when I run `node server.js` in the Command Prompt I get syntax errors.

First, it complains about `=>`. As far as I can see that's perfectly valid syntax, but if I change it to a standard anonymous function, it gets past that.

Second, it complains about the backticks in the `console.log()` line! Again, I believe this is correct syntax - I just read about template literals.

I'm a little embarrassed as this sounds like such a noob problem but can anyone (gently) tell me what stupid thing I've done?

Is it possible that an older version of node.js is on my system (one that only understands older syntax) and still taking precedence? If so, how can I find that out and correct it?

*** UPDATE ***

`node -v` reports "v0.12.2"... but I supposedly installed "20.11.1"... can the active version really be that old?!!

So it looks like the new install didn't set the newly-installed version as current... how can I fix that? I don't actually remember installing any previous version.

*** UPDATE 2 ***

My PATH had a path to both old and new versions of node.js, but the older one came first. This was my problem.

Removing the older one and restarting my Command Prompt has SOLVED the problem - their sample compiles as given now.

Comment: check `node --version`. include your own code in this post by editing it.

Comment: Version discovered, and it looks seriously wrong. Shouldn't the installer have updated that?

Comment: can you check the PATH environment variable? it'll be pointing to directory that contains your old nodejs executable.  try using `where node` to find location of node currently in use.

Comment: I think the code that you're writing is perfectly fine. The issue is with your `node` version.
I would suggest you to include the operating system on which you're currently programming this. This will help us to guide you on updating your `node` version. Also look into `nvm` which is the Node Version Manager. This will come in really handy to you.

Comment: My path contains both directories, old and new, but the old one is first - hence why it's using the older one. It's been a while but I can fix that. I appreciate the comments, thank you.